# onCLick() problem whith option and select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to use the event on click in option but not work to add a span in a `div`.

```
<option onclick="addcolore('<?php $row['title'] ?>'   this)">
    <?php $row['title'] ?>
</option>
```

and in script

```
function addcolore(title,tag) {
  var spantag = '<span class="`spanTag`">'+salam+'</span>';
  var optionTag = $(tag);
  var divrow = optionTag.parents('.row');
  divrow.append(spantag);
})
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Is this a PHP problem after all?

Comment: You havent said anything about the error you are getting

Comment: could you please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because your problem is not clear at all

Comment: you're not even outputting `<?php $row['title'] ?>`

Comment: The problem is that the event is not called and I am not added a span according jq cod to the command . Shame I do not speak English very well

Answer (score 1):

I know i shouldn't do this, but anway, i am trying to help.

First when you use your php tags, you have to use `echo` to output value, so instead of `<?php $row['title'] ?>` it should be `<?php echo $row['title']; ?>`.

Next i am not sure the events work directly on option, i've putted example of event listener on select when it changes it triggers your function for change color.

Also at function youre trying to define a class name using ` which will not work.

At function end, you should not put that extra bracket `})`

```js
var select = document.getElementById("someSelect");
function addcolore(title,tag) {
  var spantag = '<span class="spanTag">Choosen color is: '+title+'</span>';
  var optionTag = $(tag);
  var divrow = optionTag.parents('.row');
  divrow.append(spantag);
}

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    addcolore(select.value, this);
});
```

```css
.spanTag { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<select id="someSelect">
<option onclick="addcolore('red', this)">Red</option>
<option onclick="addcolore('blue', this)">Blue</option>
<option onclick="addcolore('green', this)">Green</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: who to get a data-hex attributr for  ```addcolore(select.value, this)```